# Pinia $subscribe callback "mutation.payload" property giving a Typescript warning in PhpStorm

Tags: typescript, vue.js, phpstorm, pinia

My code actually works OK, but I'm getting a Typescript warning that I don't understand.

```ts
const dashboardStore = useDashboardStore()

dashboardStore.$subscribe((mutation) => {
  // This works OK!
  console.log(mutation.payload.id)
})
```

PhpStorm gives me a warning on `mutation.payload`:

> TS2339: Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'SubscriptionCallbackMutation'.   Property 'payload' does not exist on

It correctly infers that the callback itself is a Pinia `SubscriptionCallback<DashboardState>`.

The Pinia types show the `mutation` argument as type `SubscriptionCallbackMutation<S>`, and declares that type as:

```ts
export declare type SubscriptionCallbackMutation<S> = SubscriptionCallbackMutationDirect | SubscriptionCallbackMutationPatchObject<S> | SubscriptionCallbackMutationPatchFunction;
```

And of course type `SubscriptionCallbackMutationPatchObject` has the `patch` property I need.

So if I explicitly type the callback arguments...

```ts
dashboardStore.$subscribe((mutation: SubscriptionCallbackMutation<DashboardState>) => {
  // No errors or warnings
  const typedMutation = mutation as SubscriptionCallbackMutationPatchObject<DashboardState>
  console.log(mutation.payload.id)
}
```

But I cannot specify the `mutation` argument as `SubscriptionCallbackMutationPatchObject<DashboardState>` and that's confusing to me.

Anyone understand why? And how I can accomplish this without re-typign?

Comment: Make sure code builds correctly with no TS errors, not just runs in dev server. If it's the case, check which TS version IDE uses, should likely be the one from the project and not built-in. Otherwise it's likely the bug to submit. "ut I cannot specify the mutation argument as SubscriptionCallbackMutationPatchObject<AccountUser>" - why?

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask. It does indeed build without issue. First, I realized later that the type should be `<DashboardState>` not `<AccountUser>`, but either way, when I write "I cannot specify" I am saying if I type the param that way, PhpStorm gives me an error: `TS2345: Argument of type '(mutation: SubscriptionCallbackMutationPatchObject<DashboardState>) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SubscriptionCallback<DashboardState>'.   Types of parameters 'mutation' and 'mutation' are incompatible.     Type 'SubscriptionCallbackMutation<DashboardState> is not as...` and so on.

Comment: Rest of that error is: `Type 'SubscriptionCallbackMutation<DashboardState>' is not assignable to type 'SubscriptionCallbackMutationPatchObject<DashboardState>'.       Property 'payload' is missing in type 'SubscriptionCallbackMutationDirect' but required in type 'SubscriptionCallbackMutationPatchObject<DashboardState>'.` 

Don't know why it thinks it needs to be `SubscriptionCallbackMutationDirect`.

Comment: ...Actually, it sort of makes sense to me? All we know is that it could be either the Mutation with a Patch Object or it could not be. ...So I think the solution is that I should just be checking within the code if it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that Pinia's type was definitively `SubscriptionCallbackMutation<S>`, per the declaration:

```ts
export declare type SubscriptionCallbackMutation<S> = SubscriptionCallbackMutationDirect | SubscriptionCallbackMutationPatchObject<S> | SubscriptionCallbackMutationPatchFunction;
```

...But that doesn't guarantee that it will be `SubscriptionCallbackMutationPatchObject<S>`, and hence won't have the `payload` property. It's on me to verify that.

As such, I can explicitly type the `mutation` param to `SubscriptionCallbackMutation<DashboardState>` and then just check in the method call, like this:

```ts
dashboardStore.$subscribe(async (mutation: SubscriptionCallbackMutation<DashboardState>) => {
  const params: DashboardQueryParams = {}
  if (mutation.type === MutationType.patchObject) {
    const payload = mutation.payload
    // Do stuff now that I know it's a Patch mutation.
  }
})
```